# How to sum current index with all previous numbers inside an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

I'm new with java, i mostly work with C++ and right now i'm having some trouble trying to sum all previous numbers of the current index inside an array. thanks for your help :).

```
public StaticStack<Integer> sumPrev(DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list, StaticStack<Integer> stack, int i){
    if(i < list.numElements()){
        stack.push(lista.get(i));
        i++;
        return sumPrev(listaD, pilhaS, i);
    }

    return stack;

}
```

what i need is to get lista.get(i) plus all the previous numbers inside list. Sorry for my english, still learning :(

Comment: Remove the `Stack`, return an `int`. Like `return (i > 0) ? list.get(i) + sumPrev(list, i - 1) : list.get(0);` and a `List` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do it and here it's how:

```
public StaticStack<Integer> sum(DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list, StaticStack<Integer> stack, int i, int sum){
    if(i < list.numElements()){
        if(i == 0){
            stack.push(listaD.get(i));
            sum = list.get(i);
            i++;
            return acum(list, stack, i, sum);
        }
        else{
            stack.push(list.get(i) + sum);
            sum = sum + list.get(i);
            i++;
            return acum(list, stack, i, sum);
        }
    }

    return stack;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
List<Integer> list = IntList.range(1, 10).toList();
List<Integer> sumList = new ArrayList<>();
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++) {
    sum += list.get(i);
    sumList.add(sum);
}

System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(sumList); // [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```